# How to use hyphen/dash in page's parameters in Blazor.net

Tags: c#, blazor

I want to create a page with the following parameters *number* and *year* so the users can navigate to it using the following notation http://localhost:5000/test/*number*-*year*.

When I try to do that I get the following exception

> InvalidOperationException: Invalid template
>   'Test/{number:int}-{year:int}'. The character '}' in parameter segment
>   '{number:int}-{year:int}' is not allowed.

Here's the code

```
@page "/Test/{number:int}-{year:int}"

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public int? Number {get;set;}

    [Parameter]
    public int? Year {get;set;}
}
```

How I can achieve this in Blazor?

Comment: does it work currectly if you use normal `"/Test/{number:int}/{year:int}"` routing conventions ?

Comment: if it's not working with normal routing syntax too, one reason could be your optional properties. try this `/Test/{number:int?}/{year:int?}` then this `"/Test/{number:int?}-{year:int?}"` or remove those question marks from your parameter properties